Create html table from array with calc function?
I'm trying to create an HTML page with a table that will show a list of different "objects". These objects all have a calculated value in a measuring point, and a total sum is calculated at the end (noise level). The calculated value should be recalculated to see what difference it makes to the whole value.
I've made a version that works for the 3 objects added to test the javascript. But since I have about 300 objects it's not time efficient to manually add all the objects by hand.
So, do I create a table for about 300 objects the simplest way?


window.onload = function() {
  // Assuming the input elements have ids 'input1', 'input2', etc.
  var i = 1;
  while (document.getElementById('input' + i)) {
    document.getElementById('input' + i).value = 0;
    let mp1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("mp1_" + i).innerText);
    let mp2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("mp2_" + i).innerText);
    let mp3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("mp3_" + i).innerText);
    document.getElementById("MP1sum" + i).innerText = mp1;
    document.getElementById("MP2sum" + i).innerText = mp2;
    document.getElementById("MP3sum" + i).innerText = mp3;
    document.getElementById("MP1recalc" + i).innerText = Math.pow(10, mp1 / 10);
    document.getElementById("MP2recalc" + i).innerText = Math.pow(10, mp2 / 10);
    document.getElementById("MP3recalc" + i).innerText = Math.pow(10, mp3 / 10);
    i++;
  }
  calculateTotal();

};

element.dispatchEvent(event);

function calculateSum(row) {
  let mp1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("mp1_" + row).innerText);
  let mp2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("mp2_" + row).innerText);
  let mp3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("mp2_" + row).innerText);
  let input = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input" + row).value);
  let MP1sum = mp1 - input;
  let MP2sum = mp2 - input;
  let MP3sum = mp3 - input;
  document.getElementById("MP1sum" + row).innerText = MP1sum;
  document.getElementById("MP2sum" + row).innerText = MP2sum;
  document.getElementById("MP3sum" + row).innerText = MP3sum;
  document.getElementById("MP1recalc" + row).innerText = Math.pow(10, MP1sum / 10);
  document.getElementById("MP2recalc" + row).innerText = Math.pow(10, MP2sum / 10);
  document.getElementById("MP3recalc" + row).innerText = Math.pow(10, MP3sum / 10);
  calculateTotal();
}

function calculateTotal() {
  var totalMP1 = 0;
  var totalMP2 = 0;
  var totalMP3 = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    totalMP1 += parseFloat(document.getElementById("MP1recalc" + i).innerText);
    totalMP2 += parseFloat(document.getElementById("MP2recalc" + i).innerText);
    totalMP3 += parseFloat(document.getElementById("MP3recalc" + i).innerText);
  }
  var LogTotalMP1 = 10 * Math.log10(totalMP1);
  var LogTotalMP2 = 10 * Math.log10(totalMP2);
  var LogTotalMP3 = 10 * Math.log10(totalMP3);
  document.getElementById("MP1total").innerText = Math.round(LogTotalMP1 * 10) / 10;
  document.getElementById("MP2total").innerText = Math.round(LogTotalMP2 * 10) / 10;
  document.getElementById("MP3total").innerText = Math.round(LogTotalMP3 * 10) / 10;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Bullerkälla</th>
    <th>LW</th>
    <th>MP1</th>
    <th>MP2</th>
    <th>MP3</th>
    <th>Input</th>
    <th>Sum MP1</th>
    <th>Sum MP2</th>
    <th>Sum MP3</th>
    <th style="display:none;">Recalculated Sum MP1</th>
    <th style="display:none;">Recalculated Sum MP2</th>
    <th style="display:none;">Recalculated Sum MP3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>101. Ventilationshus (Nordost)</td>
    <td id="lw1">86</td>
    <td id="mp1_1">19,1</td>
    <td id="mp2_1">-11</td>
    <td id="mp3_1">-11</td>
    <td><input type="number" id="input1" oninput="calculateSum(1)"></td>
    <td id="MP1sum1"></td>
    <td id="MP2sum1"></td>
    <td id="MP3sum1"></td>
    <td id="MP1recalc1" style="display:none;"></td>
    <td id="MP2recalc1" style="display:none;"></td>
    <td id="MP3recalc1" style="display:none;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>101. Ventilationshus (Sydväst)</td>
    <td id="lw2">86</td>
    <td id="mp1_2">-4,2</td>
    <td id="mp2_2">-5</td>
    <td id="mp3_2">-5</td>
    <td><input type="number" id="input2" oninput="calculateSum(2)"></td>
    <td id="MP1sum2"></td>
    <td id="MP2sum2"></td>
    <td id="MP3sum2"></td>
    <td id="MP1recalc2" style="display:none;"></td>
    <td id="MP2recalc2" style="display:none;"></td>
    <td id="MP3recalc2" style="display:none;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>102. Ventilationshus (Nordväst)</td>
    <td id="lw3">89</td>
    <td id="mp1_3">21,5</td>
    <td id="mp2_3">-6</td>
    <td id="mp3_3">-6</td>
    <td><input type="number" id="input3" oninput="calculateSum(3)"></td>
    <td id="MP1sum3"></td>
    <td id="MP2sum3"></td>
    <td id="MP3sum3"></td>
    <td id="MP1recalc3" style="display:none;"></td>
    <td id="MP2recalc3" style="display:none;"></td>
    <td id="MP3recalc3" style="display:none;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6">Total</td>
    <td id="MP1total"></td>
    <td id="MP2total"></td>
    <td id="MP3total"></td>
    <td colspan="2" style="display:none;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>




Much of your code is repetitive and could be simplified. Make sure that your code is working (which is not at the moment) and provide more information about the format of those objects. If the code is actually "issue-free" consider asking the question at Code Review. Also, it might be a good time to learn about looping methods such as for-, forEach-, and while-loops.

"Uncaught ReferenceError: element is not defined" woops

strange, the code and html-page works on my computer, locally. I definitely need to learn looping methods. Never coded before besides some html about 20 years ago.

Like @tacoshy mentioned, you'll need a loop to create table rows for each of your 300 objects.
Here is an example of a loop that pulls data from an object literal and creates the rows in the table. You'll have to change the new buildNoiseTable() function if your data is in another format. But this shows you the general process.
I changed the html file to only have the non-changing core of the table.
I call the new buildNoiseTable() from your window.onload function.
I also fixed one line of code in calculateSum() - see the NOTE comment under this method.
I commented out element.dispatchEvent(event), since neither element nor event are defined in the code you have here.


let NoiseData = [
  { name: "101. Ventilationshus (Nordost)", lw: 86, mp1: 19.1, mp2: -11, mp3: -11 },
  { name: "101. Ventilationshus (Sydväst)", lw: 86, mp1: -4.2, mp2: -5, mp3: -5 },
  { name: "101. Ventilationshus (Nordväst)", lw: 89, mp1: 21.5, mp2: -6, mp3: -6 },
]


function buildNoiseTable( data ) {
  let tableHtml = "";
  let id = 1;

  for( let noise of data ) {
    tableHtml += `<tr>`;
    tableHtml += `<td>${noise.name}</td> <td id="lw${id}">${noise.lw}</td> <td id="mp1_${id}">${noise.mp1}</td> <td id="mp2_${id}">${noise.mp2}</td> <td id="mp3_${id}">${noise.mp3}</td> `;
    tableHtml += `<td><input type="number" id="input${id}" oninput="calculateSum(${id})"></td>`;
    tableHtml += `<td id="MP1sum${id}"></td> <td id="MP2sum${id}"></td> <td id="MP3sum${id}"></td>`;
    tableHtml += `<td id="MP1recalc${id}" style="display:none;"></td> <td id="MP2recalc${id}" style="display:none;"></td> <td id="MP3recalc${id}" style="display:none;"></td>`;
    tableHtml += `</tr>`;

    ++id;
  }

  tableHtml += `<tr>`
  tableHtml += `<td colspan="6">Total</td> <td id="MP1total"></td> <td id="MP2total"></td> <td id="MP3total"></td> <td colspan="2" style="display:none;"></td>`
  tableHtml += `</tr>`

  document.getElementById("NoiseTableBodyID").innerHTML = tableHtml
}



window.onload = function() {
  // NOTE Added this call to create the table
  buildNoiseTable( NoiseData )

  // Assuming the input elements have ids 'input1', 'input2', etc.
  var i = 1;
  while (document.getElementById('input' + i)) {
    document.getElementById('input' + i).value = 0;
    let mp1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("mp1_" + i).innerText);
    let mp2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("mp2_" + i).innerText);
    let mp3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("mp3_" + i).innerText);
    document.getElementById("MP1sum" + i).innerText = mp1;
    document.getElementById("MP2sum" + i).innerText = mp2;
    document.getElementById("MP3sum" + i).innerText = mp3;
    document.getElementById("MP1recalc" + i).innerText = Math.pow(10, mp1 / 10);
    document.getElementById("MP2recalc" + i).innerText = Math.pow(10, mp2 / 10);
    document.getElementById("MP3recalc" + i).innerText = Math.pow(10, mp3 / 10);
    i++;
  }
  calculateTotal();

}


// lement.dispatchEvent(event);


function calculateSum(row) {
  let mp1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("mp1_" + row).innerText);
  let mp2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("mp2_" + row).innerText);
  // NOTE Fixed "mp2_" below to be "mp3_"
  let mp3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("mp3_" + row).innerText);
  let input = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input" + row).value);
  let MP1sum = mp1 - input;
  let MP2sum = mp2 - input;
  let MP3sum = mp3 - input;
  document.getElementById("MP1sum" + row).innerText = MP1sum;
  document.getElementById("MP2sum" + row).innerText = MP2sum;
  document.getElementById("MP3sum" + row).innerText = MP3sum;
  document.getElementById("MP1recalc" + row).innerText = Math.pow(10, MP1sum / 10);
  document.getElementById("MP2recalc" + row).innerText = Math.pow(10, MP2sum / 10);
  document.getElementById("MP3recalc" + row).innerText = Math.pow(10, MP3sum / 10);
  calculateTotal();
}


function calculateTotal() {
  var totalMP1 = 0;
  var totalMP2 = 0;
  var totalMP3 = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    totalMP1 += parseFloat(document.getElementById("MP1recalc" + i).innerText);
    totalMP2 += parseFloat(document.getElementById("MP2recalc" + i).innerText);
    totalMP3 += parseFloat(document.getElementById("MP3recalc" + i).innerText);
  }
  var LogTotalMP1 = 10 * Math.log10(totalMP1);
  var LogTotalMP2 = 10 * Math.log10(totalMP2);
  var LogTotalMP3 = 10 * Math.log10(totalMP3);
  document.getElementById("MP1total").innerText = Math.round(LogTotalMP1 * 10) / 10;
  document.getElementById("MP2total").innerText = Math.round(LogTotalMP2 * 10) / 10;
  document.getElementById("MP3total").innerText = Math.round(LogTotalMP3 * 10) / 10;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Bullerkälla</th> <th>LW</th> <th>MP1</th> <th>MP2</th> <th>MP3</th> <th>Input</th>
      <th>Sum MP1</th> <th>Sum MP2</th> <th>Sum MP3</th>
      <th style="display:none;">Recalculated Sum MP1</th> <th style="display:none;">Recalculated Sum MP2</th>
      <th style="display:none;">Recalculated Sum MP3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="NoiseTableBodyID">
    <!-- Poplulated by javascript -->
  </tbody>
</table>




you should rather use createElement instead of creating HTML from strings + (unsafe) innerHTML. Then use small discrete functions rather than large ones. Combine repetitive code and you properly can reduce your code by 70%

@tacoshy, I added one small function. My intent was not to rewrite the original posters whole program for him, but to answer the question about how to handle a large number of objects.

Thanks all for the answers! Much appreciated!
